# Solving a matrix differential equation $dx(t)/dt = A(x) x(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$. With $B$ a constant $n \times n$ matrix, we have the differential equation :

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = - \textrm{diag}(x(t)) B x(t)$$

I am trying to write $x(1)$ in terms of $x(0)$.

Comment: The title is missing the $-{\rm diag}(x(t))$ part. And $B$ is constant, right?

Comment: Yeah B is constant. A(x) in the title refers to the product: - diag(x) B

Comment: This reminds me of [Hopfield networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network?wprov=sfla1) so my feeling is that it will not have an explicit solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an answer, if $B$ is **diagonal**, but I made a *mistake* earlier and it's to long for a comment.

Let $B=\operatorname{diag}(b_1, \ldots, b_n) $, then $$\frac{dx_i(t) }{dt}=-b_i(x_i(t))^2.$$

From $$\int_{x_i(0)}^{x_i(t)}-\frac{dx_i}{x_i^2}=\int_0^tb_i\ dt$$ follows $$\frac{1}{x_i(t)}-\frac{1}{x_i(0)}=b_it.$$

Hence, $$x_i(t) =\begin{cases}\frac{1}{b_it+\frac{1}{x_i(0)}},&x_i(0)\neq 0\\0,&x_i(0)=0\end{cases}.$$

Hopefully it can be generalized to diagonalizable matrices.